# AngularJS resolve promise before load route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make promise inside a factory and then validate in `locationChangeStart`. The problem is that the `locationChangeStart` doesn't wait for my promise. What can I do to make my promise wait to complete?

Here is my code,

```
app.run(['$rootScope','$location','KeyFactory', 
function($root, $location,KeyFactory) {

    $root.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, curr, prev) {

    KeyFactory.check();
    console.log(KeyFactory.GetKeyPass()); ///PRINT undefined
    if(KeyFactory.GetKeyPass()== true){

       console.log('authorised');

    }else{
       $location.path('/login');
  }

    });

}]);


app.factory('KeyFactory', ['$http','$log', function($http,$log) {

    var key = {};
    key.setKeyPass = function(set) {
                        key.Status = set;
                    }

    key.GetKeyPass = function() {
                        return key.Status;
                    }

    key.check = function(){
                                    $http.post('http://localhost/api/CheckPass').success(function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    key.setKeyPass(true);

}).error(function (data, status){

    $log.error("error you cant acess here!");
    console.log(status);

     });

         }

return key;

}]);
```

Comment: Can use a router `resolve` that is what they are for. Which router are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous code doesn't work in synchronous way as you are thinking. After making an ajax it doesn't respond in the next line. In angular after making an ajax it return an `promise` object which is responsible to tell that `response/error` is going to happen.

There are couple of things missing in your code.

1. You should return a promise from the `check` method of service.
2. Then put `.then` function on `check` method promise & expect response in its success/error callback.

**Code**

```
key.check = function(){
 return $http.post('http://localhost/api/CheckPass').then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    key.setKeyPass(true);
 }, function (response){
    key.setKeyPass(false);
});
```

**Run**

```
KeyFactory.check().then(function(){

  if(KeyFactory.GetKeyPass()== true){
       console.log('authorised');
    }else{
       $location.path('/login');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works, but if i type /securityPage i still can see the template before go to /login and the controllers of /securityPage still load too.

Comment: @John resolve would help you in that situation.. put resolver on your state/route